# How to maintain Android Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I created a simple example application that creates a button in MainActivity to call the SecondActivity.
The application works well.

But I found something strange.
If I press the home key to go outside and run the launcher of the application, it returns to Main Activity, not SecondActivity.

Through a search, I got the following guide:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondMainActivity.class);

 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); //<- add option

 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //<- add option

 startActivity(intent);
```

This confirmed that the Activity was maintained as I wanted.

However, when using the back key, the application program ended without returning to MainActivity!

The questions I want to ask are as follows.

1. How to maintain SecondActivity when I press the home key to go outside and run the program again without terminating the program in SecondActivity.
2. How to return to Main Activity when I press the back key in Second Activity.

I hope 1) and 2) will be satisfied at once.

Source code is as follows

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondMainActivity"
            android:label="SecondMainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.myapplication2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button GoToNewActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GoToNewActivity = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        GoToNewActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Intent code for open new activity through intent.

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondMainActivity.class);

//                //[1]
//                //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//                //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//
//                //[2]
//                intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

SecondMainActivity

```
package com.example.myapplication2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;

public class SecondMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

You can [download the application source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rWhdyjxAqPTo3g9XB5PhkO5jdvyzs7eB/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: The activities are arranged in a stack—```the back stack```—in the order in which each activity is opened.

Answer (score 0):

- 1.If you going to home screen that because of your app is restarting
  android system  clear memory automatically after some time.

  2.You don't need "intent.flag" tags , just start the activity and as Gunesh Shanbhag   said in comment activity are arranged in stack. You
  don't need to write code for    that is automatic process but you can
  ovveride the onbackpressed method to do    something else like press
  back button twice to exit the app.